# Do you "inaugurate"or "launch" or "open" a new book?

Tags: word-choice

My friend is going to publish a new book and the opening ceremony is tomorrow. However, do I say that she is "launching" a new book?

Is there a better or more accurate way of saying this?

Comment: Certainly do not use a misspelled word *inaugerate*.  (Unless it is a book on spelling and you want to be clever-seeming.)

Comment: @GEdgar: thank you for pointing that out :P Typing error...

Comment: Of these three choices, I would say "launch".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Books, like ships, are 'launched'.

OED has:

> **book launch** n.
>
> 1964   Guardian 25 Aug. 4 (headline)    *Book-launch at the Sycamore.*
>
> 2000   J. Pemberton Forever & Ever Amen 4   *If someone's stupid enough to publish the damn thing then there's..book launches, readings and other such nonsense. Knowing my luck, I say, it'll become a bestseller.*

["book, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014. Web. 21 November 2014.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21412)

Answer (score 4):

First choice is "Book Launch".

> [To launch](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/launch) something is to propel it or get it going, usually from a standing position. *You can launch a rocket, a career, a **product** or even a watermelon*. 
>   Either way, you're getting it off the ground.
>
> [To inaugurate](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inaugrate#word=inaugurate) means to start something, to give it a kick off.

```
        A new book was launched by me.
        The book was inaugurated by you.
```

While inaugurate (AmE) has long been used in formal contexts, such as the swearing-in ceremony that inaugurates a President's term in office, inaugurate is now also used casually.

```
You might inaugurate your marathon training with a long run.
```

Comment: You definitely can't [inaugurate](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93195) a book in British English.

Comment: Concede, post updated.

Comment: @AE, nor does one inaugurate a tangible thing in American English.  Instead we inaugurate [processes, courses, or operations](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begin).

Comment: @pilcrow: Also people, I'm thinking?

Comment: @AE, yes, but specifically inaugurating a person into a formal office of some kind.

Comment: @pilcrow, oh yes, absolutely.